# Sorting a number which is stored as varchar in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, sorting

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Fac__Invoice` ORDER BY `Fac__Invoice`.`invoice_number` ASC
```

The result is this table:

[image]

The problem is that number 10 is after 1. It should be after 9. This is because invoice_number is a varchar. I deliberately choose varchar because i want to store numbers like for example "FA001".

Can you write a sql query so that invoice_number 10 will be placed underneath 9? 
Or is there any other solution?

Comment: Add another column to your table where you just store the invoice number. You get to keep your `FA001` as it is, but you can order and manipulate things around using another int column where actual number of invoice is stored. That avoids the need to cast from char to int when you want to deal with numbers.

Comment: @N.B. Storing an information twice is not a goot idea.

Comment: @Jens - I disagree, it is completely need dependent on what you do. For this particular case, there is literally no harm in doing so, and gain is significant. Being exclusive like that yields horrible results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to caste the value to unsigned:

```
SELECT * FROM `Fac__Invoice` ORDER BY CAST(`Fac__Invoice`.`invoice_number` AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```